# Mocking/Stubbing globals in sails.js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sails.js

In Sails.js we've created a wrapper around logging functionality so that security audit logs have the same format and information etc.

I'd like to unit test the wrapper that in turn calls `sails.log.info`. How can I mock/stub the global sails.log.info and then verify that it was called? I've used proxyquire and rewire before but they were in the context of stubbing out modules that were `required` into the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's JavaScript so you can simply overwrite it and then return the original method

```
var originalLogFunction = sails.log.info;
var actualArgs;
sails.log.info = function(arg1, arg2){
    actualArgs = { arg1: arg1, arg2: arg2 };
}

// call your method that you test here

sails.log.info = originalLogFunction;

// assert your actualArgs have the correct args
```

You can only count the number of times the method was called

You can look into the library [MoqJs](https://github.com/slavik57/moqjs/blob/master/README.md). It's a mocking library for JavaScript based on the ideas of Moq for C#

Comment: `sails` is a global variable and so I could just stub it out directly like you mentioned. One qwirk was that `sails` was only available from within the mocha's `it` function.

Comment: Yes you should do in within the test, or if you are doing a group of tests that requiring this you can overwrite the function in the beforeEach and restore inside the afterEach